# java.lang.NullPointerException: null when parsing a string parameter from url to Long, Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my controller which gets the id from the url :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"getId"})
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getClientStat(@RequestParam(value="getId", required = true) String getId) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    long userId=0;
    userId=Long.parseLong(getId);
    Client c=userService.getUserById(userId);

    modelAndView.addObject("userName", c.getName() );

    modelAndView.setViewName("user/users");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This returns a null pointer exception but the thing is when I just put getID in the modelAndView, like this :

```
    modelAndView.addObject("id",getId)
```

It does add the responding id.
How can I fix this ? I think the problem is when parsing the string,cuz when that part is removed, it works well.

Comment: "id" and "getId" are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

`parseLong` cannot return null - It either returns a `long` value or throws an Exception. So your problem is most likely not string parsing.

Check in which line the NullPointerException happens. I would expect that either `userService` is null, or the returned Client `c` is null. I guess it's probably `c` that is null - Maybe you got an ID that your user service did not find, and it returned `null` as a result...

Comment: It is actually the userService that returns a null. I apologize.
But in userService I have :
public User getUserById(long id);
whose implementation is :

public Client getUserById(long id) {
  return userRepository.findOne(id);
 }

So I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't find the user

Comment: No need to apologize - I'm glad I could help (at least a little - I hope) ;) But without further info, I cannot answer why your repository does not find a user :( Also, I think it's not the scope of this question anymore.

Comment: I understand. Thank you! :)